# Fast Search With Django + PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, full-text-search

I am newbie working on Django with PostgreSQL database. I want to know that, what are the most efficient approaches for fast search on large data (millions of records). because I ran query on 300K records, it took too much time.

How can I do fast search in Django?

Comment: Need more clarity. Please add some details, what all have you tried so far. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Indexing your db might help

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using **Django** with **PostgreSQL** the easiest way to improve your search speed and accuracy is to use **full-text search** with **indexes**.

You can read about it in the [Full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) section of the Django documentation.

If you need a tutorial about the subject you can read the article 
[Full-Text Search in Django with PostgreSQL](https://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql/)